# Concise whole float checks

Tags: python, exception, integer, typechecking

I want to improve my coding.

Recently I was thinking through some code I'd written as part of a constructor in Python. The constructor only allows integers, or whole number floats. I came up with a few ways to check this, but wanted to put it out here to see if there is perhaps a more concise way to do this double exception check.

**Method 1:**
The try, except.

```
try:
  if not float(x).is_integer:
    raise ValueError('X must be a whole number float')
except:
  raise ValueError('X must be an int or a float'):
```

**Method 2:**
The double if.

```
if not isinstance(x, (int, float)):
    raise ValueError('X must be an int or whole number float.')

elif not float(x).is_integer():
    raise ValueError('X must be a whole number float.')
```

**Method 3:** Disallow any non-integer.

```
if not isinstance(x, int):
    raise ValueError('X must be an int.')
```

I want to see what the best way to do this would be. Method 3 will save some lines of code, although it adds unnecessary restrictions on the code. Methods 1 and 2 are more flexible and reflective of the intent of the checks- to provide flexibility and transparency into why the inputs are not accepted.

Is there a more concise way to perform the above check?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a more compact way to check. First think about what it is you want to check. You care about two things: integer or whole number float. Luckily Python conditionals are short circuit evaluations for `or` and `and` meaning they don't need to evaluate the entire condition if one of the conditions "short circuits" the rest.

You don't need to worry about surrounding things in a try-except if you first check that it's an instance of either an `int` or `float`:

```py
In [37]: class T:
    ...:     def __init__(self, val):
    ...:         if not (isinstance(val, (int, float)) and float(val).is_integer()):
    ...:             raise Exception(f'{val} must be a whole number float or integer')
    ...:

In [38]: T(12)
Out[38]: <__main__.T at 0x2605d2174f0>

In [39]: T(14.)
Out[39]: <__main__.T at 0x2605d1dda60>

In [40]: T('hello')  # Raises exception
```

Because the `isinstance` is first, if that doesn't pass because I pass in a string, it will never try to convert it to a float.

Comment: Now say we had several different parameters coming in, like 2 numbers that need to have the same check. Would it be 'pythonic' to have something as long as:

if not (all isinstance(i, (int, float)) for i in [bound1, bound2] and \
            (float(i).is_integer() for i in [bound1, bound2])):

^ not sure the above will run, just a rough outline

Comment: If you wanted to, sure. I don't like list comprehension when it becomes that long though and would prefer reading something like `for var in (bound1, bound2) ....`. If you have a lot of arguments though you may want to pass in `*args` or `**kwargs`.

Comment: I think the less code in that double check the better, so I made a private method and checked both using your short-circuit expression above: if not (self.__check_validity(x1) and self.__check_validity(x2)):